# how to pass values from .ts/html to css/scss in Angular?

Tags: angular, mean-stack

i am building a MEAN stack application, and i need to change the theme color of the application by user and save it in mongo so every time the user open the application it will be the same color in the data base could you please help me doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - you can make a list of the desired colors saved in the database and part of a specific API response.

2 - you should implement all related CSS/SCSS Colors in your Angular App.

3- then you handle the API response to match which CSS/SCSS to be implemented depends on the API Response.